# Pinch UITesting iOS - zoomOut not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I want to automate (validate) the zoomIn - zoomOut for GoogleMapView in iOS with UI Testing.

With the following code, I'm able to zoomIn (and it's working correctly):

`mapView.pinch(withScale: 1.8, velocity: 1)`

But I can't zoomOut, I tried the following options:

`mapView.pinch(withScale: 1.2, velocity: 1)` (I was thinking that this will zoomOut, because the previous scale was to `1.8`, but not)

Also try using values between (0,1) ~ but this is just moving the map (not zoomIn)

`mapView.pinch(withScale: 0.7, velocity: -1)`
`mapView.pinch(withScale: 0.9, velocity: -0.9)`

Comment: I was trying to reproduce this issue, but I was unable to do that. Can you share an example project?